# Cannot find symbol, though it is defined in java

Tags: java

```
public class CategoryObservationType extends CategoryObservation
{
private String code;
private String name;
private String categories;
private int catlimit = 1;
String[] Categories;

public CategoryObservationType(String name, String code)
{
  this.name = name;
  this.code = code;
  Categories[catlimit] = new Categories(name,code);
  catlimit ++;
}

public String getCode()
{
  return code;
}
public String getName()
{
  return name;
}


public String setName(String name)
{
  this.name = name;
  return name;
}
public String setCode(String code)
{
   this.code = code;
   return code;
}
}
```

i'm new and i don't understand why im getting an output error of cannot find symbol Categories it is happening on line 24, categories[catlimit] = new categories(name,code);

Comment: I cannot see any definitions of class `Categories`. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You have a `String Categories`; that isn't a class and it isn't an array.

Comment: [Coundl't reproduce](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/HOpmflDgP4RZpTWM).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch No, there is not `String Categories;` but `private String categories;` and `String[] Categories;`. Latter is an array.

Comment: There is no `categories[catlimit] = new categories(name,code);` line in this posted code.

Answer (score 1):

You've defined `Categories` as a String array:

```
String[] Categories;
```

If that was your intent, you would need to initialize it as a String array. However, I see that you've done the following:

```
Categories[/*some index*/] = new Categories(name,code);
```

To me, this indicates that you want an *array* of `Category` objects, presumably using `catLimit` as the size of the array (*note: I'm coding from the hip -- this might not work!*):

```
// Your field:
private Category[] categories = new Category[catLimit];
...
// In your method:
categories[/*some index*/] = new Category(name,code);
```

If that's the case, then you also need to define `Category` as an object. This said, I see your class `CategoryObservationType`: I presume this is the `Category` object? If so, the code I've noted changes to this (*again, coding from the hip*):

```
// Your field:
private CategoryObservationType[] categories = new CategoryObservationType[catLimit];
...
// In your method:
categories[/*some index*/] = new CategoryObservationType(name,code);
```

You'll see here that I've replaced `catLimit` in your method with `/*some index*/`. If `catLimit` is the size of the array, as I suspect it is, then using it as your index will give you an exception for accessing a space out of the array. If you come from another programming language, I know that might seem counterintuitive: other languages allow you to use the `myArray[sizeOfArray] = elementToAppend` syntax to extend the array. *You can't do that in Java:* you need to either create a new array, or, more easily, simply use a `LinkedList` as your collection type. You'll be able to index into it using `get(index)` and add to it using `add(index)`.

Hopefully that helps!